# Issue in loading JSP page using JQuery-struts -ajax

Tags: jsp, jquery, struts2

Hi I have one select option tag in page. I need to change the content of this select box depending upon the value of other select box. We are using AJAX to do this.

Select tag of which value is supposed to get change is.

```
<tr>
    <td width="45%" align="right">
        <font class="formLabelFont1"><s:text name="tempName"/>: </font>
    </td>               
    <td align="left">
        <div id="indexDiv">
            <s:select   name="vo.indexId" 
                        id="vo.indexId" 
                        list="indexList" 
                        listKey="id" 
                        listValue="name" 
                        size="1" 
                        required="true" 
                        onchange="someFunction();"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="left"><font class="errorMessageFont"></font></td>
</tr>
```

This is a ajax call to load new value of select option tag.

```
$("#indexDiv").load(url, "key="+value, function(){
        someOtherFunction();
    });
```

This is the JSP page that is supposed to get loaded in IndexDiv

```
<s:select name="vo.indexId"
    id="vo.indexId" list="indexList" listKey="id" listValue="name" size="1"
    required="true" onchange="someFunction();" />
```

After ajax call the content of indexDiv tag is as follows.

```
<tr>
    <td width="45%" align="right">
        <font class="formLabelFont1">Index : </font>
    </td>               
    <td align="left">
        <div id="indexDiv">
            <tr>
                <td class="tdLabel"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="vo.indexId" size="1" id="vo.indexId" onchange="someFunction();">
                        <option value="1">someValue1</option>
                        <option value="2">someValue2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        </td>
            <td align="left"><font class="errorMessageFont"></font>
        </td>
</tr>
```

**So 'indexDiv' should contain only select option tag. But it contains table row instead. This issue arises only when JQuery is used to make ajax call. But when plane javascript is used this issue is not observed.**

If this is issue related to struts2 then it should have also appeared when I used non-jquery way to make ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! dont blame jQuery. Did you try using `<s:set name="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />` on the top of the source JSP page. Or, in `struts.xml`:

```
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
</struts>
```

Comment: Mother of GOD. I searched all day and I didn't find anything like this. I need to improve my Googling skills :P AWESOME.

Comment: even me also learnt this trick from stackoverflow only ! google didnt help at that time. thanks anyway.